# How can I pass an absolute URL to Api.Get method in Zebble?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-zebble, zebble

I tried to get products with the following code:

```
public static async Task<List<Product>> GetProducts()
{
    return await Get<List<Product>>("http://locahost:5919/api/products");
}
```

But it seems that Get method accepts just relative URLs and I have to pass absolute URL in Api.Base.Url setting in Config.xml file.

I also tried assigning absolute URL via BaseUrl property before return statement, but it didn't make any difference.

Another strange thing is that if I insert a fake URL (e.g. http://www.yahoo.com) as the Api.Base.Url value and run the project, the following error occurs.
[Error when adding a fake URL for Api.Base.Url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCLui.png)

So if we need to make requests to different End Points in different URLs in one project, how can we achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is incorrect. When you call:

```
Api.Get<TResponse>(someUrl);
```

Then:

- If someUrl starts with ***http://*** or ***https://*** then it will be treated as an **absolute** URL.
- Otherwise, it will be treated as relative, in which case to find the absolute Url, Zebble will prefix that with the config value of **Api.Base.Url**.

**Example:**

If in your *config.xml* file you have:

```
<Api.Base.Url>https://my-server.com</Api.Base.Url>
```

Then the following line will send a HTTP request to "https://my-server.com/api/hello":

```
Api.Get<TResponse>("api/hello");
```

But the value of ***Api.Base.Url*** in your config.xml file will be ignored in the following call (as it's an absolute url):

```
Api.Get<TResponse>("https://some-absolute-url.com/...");
```